# Prevent duplicate enteries being inserted into SQL server db?

Tags: sql, if-statement, xmlhttprequest, duplicates

net, razor, webmatrix, working with .cshtml pages.

I am using a jQuery to open a modal form and using that form to insert data into the SQL db (SQLExpress 2012). I am trying to restrict duplicate enteries by using the following code but get a message from web page [object XMLHttpReques] instead.

AddDiscount.cshtml code is:

```
@{


   if(IsPost){

        var db = Database.Open("A-LensCatFE-01SQL") ; 

        var CCode=UrlData[0];

        var Q1 = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblPromos WHERE CustomerCode =@0";
        var ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(Q1, CCode);

        if(ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
          {
                 MessageBox.Show("Duplicates");
          }
        else
        {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblPromos (CustomerID, CustomerCode,  Discount, VAT, VATRate, iScription, SRPBasedOn)" + 
            "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6)";

        var customerid = Request["customerid"];
        var customercode = Request["customercode"];
        var discount = Request["discount"];
        var vat = Request["vat"] == "on" ? true : false;
        var vatrate = Request["vatrrate"];
        var iscription = Request["iscription"];
        var srpbasedon = Request["srpbasedon"];

        db.Execute(sql, customerid, customercode,  discount, vat, vatrate, iscription, srpbasedon);

        }
       }
 }
```

Your help is needed, many thanks.

Stored Procedure code is:

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spDiscDup

```
@CustomerID int =NULL,
@CustomerCode nvarchar(max)=NULL,
@Discount decimal(5,2)=NULL,
@VAT bit =NULL,
@VATRate decimal (5,2)=NULL,
@iScription money=NULL,

    AS
    BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblPromos WHERE CustomerCode=@CustomerCode)
 ("Duplicates")
  ELSE
 INSERT INTO dbo.tblPromos (CustomerID, CustomerCode,  Discount, VAT, VATRate,            iScription, SRPBasedOn)" + 
          "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6)
```

END
GO

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a stored procedure and check there if record is exist or not before inserting.

```
If not exist 
 Then insert it
Else
 Return -1 -- means records exist/ Your prefer Msg/ any number
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am a noob and hence need a bit more help for me to understand what I need to do.

Comment: Do you mean, How to create store procedure ?

Comment: I have made  a start but need some help to recetify my errors with it:

Comment: GO through this : 
http://trappedinhoth.blogspot.in/2010/09/stored-procedures-and-webmatrix.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126898/Sql-Server-How-to-write-a-Stored-procedure-in-Sql

Comment: I can't post the code because it has many @ and stackoverflow thinks I am alerting many users!! Help how can I place the code here?

Comment: Hi I have edited my original q and now have included the SP. I am getting errors under @CustomerCode and the placeholders.

Comment: IF NOT EXISTS.
This is your condition. 
try this. Add "NOT"

Comment: IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblPromos WHERE CustomerCode=@CustomerCode)
    Begin
 INSERT INTO dbo.tblPromos (CustomerID, CustomerCode,  Discount, VAT, VATRate,            iScription, SRPBasedOn)" + 
          "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6)
    END